# How can i upload to a directory ? Ajax Post Request PHP Upload

Tags: php, ajax, upload, directory

This is part of a php/ajax upload script.
Anyone know how to upload into a directory ?

```
<?php

if(isset($_FILES["imageNameHere"]) && !empty($_FILES["imageNameHere"])) {
// Random name
$name= rand(10, 20).'.png';
// Move the file
//move_uploaded_file($_FILES["imageNameHere"]['tmp_name'], $name);//orginal

move_uploaded_file( $_FILES["imageNameHere"]["tmp_name"],$name, "uploads/" .  
$_FILES['imageNameHere']['tmp_name'][$name]); // My Try

// Return name
echo $name;
}
?>
```

Comment: It's a very painful process to ajax `files` to a server side script. You might try: http://fineuploader.com/

Comment: @SamuelCook I interpret his question as saying that he knows how to upload with AJAX, he just wants to change where the script puts the file.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Yes i wanted change the upload directory ( its for a webgl user gallery of snapshots of 3d models) and save eventually the path in mysql database.
actually i can upload to the root directory of the mainscript but not in custom dirs because i dont know how to add the code.

Answer (score 1):

This should work, Change:

```
move_uploaded_file( $_FILES["imageNameHere"]["tmp_name"],$name, "uploads/" . $_FILES['imageNameHere']['tmp_name'][$name]); // My Try
```

To:

```
move_uploaded_file( $_FILES["imageNameHere"]["tmp_name"], "uploads/" . $name);
```

You will run into problems when `rand()` generates the same number twice however.

Comment: Hi thanks for your hints.
I Changed the Code @ user1909426 and i created the uploads directory with write permissions but strangeful i upload actually only in the root directory.

I Check the alternative with fineuploader eventually i can integrate it into the webgl modelviewer with snapshot for this is the upload function.

Comment: Ahh good, so it's uploading now. You should try to use the full file path in `move_uploaded_file()`, i.e. `move_uploaded_file($_FILES["imageNameHere"]["tmp_name"], "/www/uploads/" . $name);`

Comment: yep and the rand uploaded files overwrite if filename exists

Comment: With the absolute path it didnt upload anything. With the short path it uploads in the root.

Comment: Hi ,
With this :
move_uploaded_file( $_FILES["imageNameHere"]["tmp_name"], "uploads/" . $name); 
It upload the image but it is only in uploads if the image in root directory exists.
Is it possible to upload direct in uploads ?